# How to calculate $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ if $\sin_1 \phi= \cos_1 \phi$ and $\sin_2 \phi= \cos_2 \phi$?

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

EDIT: I've noticed that I did the conjugation calculation wrong. The result is $-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}i$. I've corrected it in the rest of the body.
EDIT2: Further corrections made, Problem still exists.

I am currently practicing complex numbers using a textbook and I came across an exercise which confused me.

The exercise is: Given a quotient of two complex numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$ as $\frac{z_1}{z_2}$, calculate the fraction first by using the conjugate of the complex number and then calculate the fraction by first turning $z_1$ and $z_2$ into the exponential form.

In this exercise, $\frac{z_1}{z_2} = \frac{1 + \sqrt3 + (1 - \sqrt3)i}{1 - \sqrt3 + (1 + \sqrt3)i}$

The problem I seem to face now, is this: I have calculated the absolute value for both Z numbers and through my calculations it equals $\sqrt8$. The tangent for a reason I don't understand yet, equals $-2 + \sqrt3$ for $z_1$, but $-2 - \sqrt3$ for $z_2$ which already seems contradictory since the tangent function is never greater than 1. I've also calculated that $\sin_1 \phi= \frac{1 - \sqrt3}{\sqrt8} = \cos_2 \phi$ and $\sin_2 \phi= \frac{1 + \sqrt3}{\sqrt8} = \cos_1 \phi$.

Since I can't tell for which $\phi$ values these sin and cos values correlate and I couldn't find a way to find cos(x and y) sin(x and y) to reversely build up a cosine subtraction rule and a sine identity rule, I tried (as seen in the picture below) by finding a pattern of subtracting $\frac{11\pi}{6} - \frac{4\pi}{6}$ because those values are similar (including the signs) to the values I've gotten for the exercise.

I personally assume therefore, that the result I hypothetically should be getting from $\alpha_1 - \alpha_2$ should be $\sin_3 \phi= \frac{-\sqrt3+1}{\sqrt8}$ and $\cos_3 \phi= \frac{-\sqrt3-1}{\sqrt8}$ (After rechecking and correcting the values, this seems to be wrong)

Combined with the fact that $\frac{r_1}{r_2} = \frac{\sqrt8}{\sqrt8} = 1$ these results wouldn't add up because the result of $\frac{r1}{r2} \times (\cos\Delta\alpha + \sin\Delta\alpha) = \frac{-1}{2} \times \sqrt3 $ which is inequal to the result $-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}i$ I got from directly solving the fraction via multiplication with the conjugate.

Now my question is, I am pretty sure I have made a fault somewhere, however I can't tell where. Are my direct calculations faulty, are my calculations of the values used for the exponential forms of $z_1$ or $z_2$ faulty or is there some strategy to solving this exercise I don't know about.

I have uploaded a Photo of my Notes on this exercise.

Thank you in advance for your time and explanation or correction.

[image: Updated photo]

Comment: Terminology:  the "inverse" of a non-zero complex number is it's reciprocal.  You mean the "conjugate". $\overline {a+bi}=a-bi$ if $a,b\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: @lulu Thanks. Edited the question.

Comment: Note that $z_1 \overline{z_1} = - z_2 \overline{z_2}$

Comment: @asymptotic Why should I note that, since I am multiplying $z1\conjugate z2 in the upper part of the fraction? Please explain further.

Comment: The tangent function can in fact be greater than $1$. It's range is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @asymptotic, that's incorrect. Since for any $z\in\Bbb C$ we have $z\overline z=|z|^2,$ the identity you claim could only be true if $|z_1|=|z_2|=0,$ which would mean that $z_1=z_2=0,$ which would mean in turn that $1=\pm\sqrt{3}.$

Comment: @CameronBuie I find that $z_1 \overline{z_1} = 4 \sqrt{3}$ and $z_2 \overline{z_2}=-4 \sqrt{3}$.

Comment: @asymptotic, you have obtained an incorrect value for $\left\lvert z_1\right\rvert^2$ and an impossible value for $\left\lvert z_2\right\rvert^2,$ then.

Answer (score 1):

> The exercise is: Given a quotient of two complex numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$ as $\frac{z_1}{z_2}$, calculate the fraction first by using the conjugate of the complex number and then calculate the fraction by first turning $z_1$ and $z_2$ into the exponential form.

> In this exercise, $\frac{z_1}{z_2} = \frac{1 + \sqrt3 + (1 - \sqrt3)i}{1 - \sqrt3 + (1 + \sqrt3)i}$

I believe you mean that $z_1=1+\sqrt{3}+\left(1-\sqrt{3}\right)i$ and $z_2=1-\sqrt{3}+\left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)i.$

You've correctly performed the calculation in the first way, if that is what you mean. However, you could just as easily set $$z_1=\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{2}i$$ and $$z_2=\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2}i,$$ for example, and still have $\frac{z_1}{z_2} = \frac{1 + \sqrt3 + (1 - \sqrt3)i}{1 - \sqrt3 + (1 + \sqrt3)i}.$

> The problem I seem to face now, is this: I have calculated the absolute value for both Z numbers and through my calculations it equals $\sqrt8$.

That's correct, *if* you meant what I think you meant above. On the other hand, it would *not* be correct for the examples I gave, and their common absolute value would instead be $\sqrt{2}$ in that case.

> The tangent for a reason I don't understand yet, equals $-2 + \sqrt3$ for $z_1$, but $-2 - \sqrt3$ for $z_2$ which already seems contradictory since the tangent function is never greater than 1.

As pointed out in the comments above, this isn't unusual, at all. While the sine and cosine functions are bounded on the real number line, the tangent function is not.

> I've also calculated that $\sin_1 \phi= \frac{1 - \sqrt3}{\sqrt8} = \cos_2 \phi$ and $\sin_2 \phi= \frac{1 + \sqrt3}{\sqrt8} = \cos_1 \phi$.

I believe you mean that if $z_1=\cos\left(\phi_1\right)+i\sin\left(\phi_1\right)$ and $z_2=\cos\left(\phi_2\right)+i\sin\left(\phi_2\right),$ then $$\sin\left(\phi_1\right)=\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{8}}=\cos\left(\phi_2\right)$$ and $$\sin\left(\phi_2\right)=\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{8}}=\cos\left(\phi_1\right).$$ These are both true equations, and will be **very helpful values** later.

> Since I can't tell for which $\phi$ values these sin and cos values correlate and I couldn't find a way to find cos(x and y) sin(x and y) to reversely build up a cosine subtraction rule and a sine identity rule, I tried (as seen in the picture below) by finding a pattern of subtracting $\frac{11\pi}{6} - \frac{4\pi}{6}$ because those values are similar (including the signs) to the values I've gotten for the exercise.

$\cos\left(\frac{11\pi}{6}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}=\sin\left(\frac{4\pi}{6}\right)$ and $\sin\left(\frac{11\pi}{6}\right)=-\frac12=\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{6}\right),$ but neither of those two numbers is what you should be working with, and I'm not sure in what way you feel them to be "similar" to the correct numbers. Regardless, though, as you noted, it led you to incorrect conclusions when you attempted to use these substitute angles to try to infer what would happen in this case.

It seems that you're uncertain about *how* to convert your numbers to exponential form. Here's how I would approach it. You've actually already done all the work you need to do, as it turns out!

Now, since $|z_1|=|z_2|=\sqrt{8},$ we know that there *are* angles $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ such that $z_1=\sqrt{8}e^{i\phi_1}$ and $z_2=\sqrt{8}e^{i\phi_2},$ and using these exponential forms, we get $$\frac{z_1}{z_2}=\frac{e^{i\phi_1}}{e^{i\phi_2}}=e^{i\left(\phi_1-\phi_2\right)}=\cos\left(\phi_1-\phi_2\right)+i\sin\left(\phi_1-\phi_2\right).$$ Using angle difference formulas gives us $$\cos\left(\phi_1-\phi_2\right)=\cos(\phi_1)\cdot\cos(\phi_2)+\sin(\phi_1)\sin(\phi_2)$$ and $$\sin\left(\phi_1-\phi_2\right)=\sin(\phi_1)\cdot\cos(\phi_2)-\cos(\phi_1)\cdot\sin(\phi_2).$$ Now we can use the **very helpful values** you found earlier to see that $$\cos\left(\phi_1-\phi_2\right)=\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{8}}\cdot\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{8}}+\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{8}}\cdot\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{8}}=\frac{-2}{8}+\frac{-2}{8}=-\frac{4}{8}=-\frac{1}{2}$$ and that $$\sin\left(\phi_1-\phi_2\right)=\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{8}}\right)^2-\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{8}}\right)^2=\frac{4-2\sqrt{3}}{8}-\frac{4+2\sqrt{3}}{8}=\frac{-4\sqrt{3}}{8}=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.$$ Hence, just as before $$\frac{z_1}{z_2}=\cos\left(\phi_1-\phi_2\right)+i\sin\left(\phi_1-\phi_2\right)=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i.$$

But wait...we never actually found the angles! Since the angle difference formulas don't require us to know the values of the angles (or even the value of their difference), but merely their respective sines and cosines, we got to skip that step, altogether, this time.

---

***If I did*** want to find angles, here's how I might approach it. First, I would imagine drawing a segment from the origin to $z_1$ and another to $z_2.$ We need to find an angle to these segments from the positive real axis.

Noting that $1+\sqrt{3}>0$ and $1-\sqrt{3}<0,$ the segment to $z_1$ is in the fourth quadrant, so the slope of the segment to $z_1$ is simply the tangent of an angle from the positive real axis to the segment. The slope of the segment is simply $$\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{1+\sqrt{3}}=\frac{\left(1-\sqrt{3}\right)^2}{\left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)\cdot\left(1-\sqrt{3}\right)}=\frac{1-2\sqrt{3}+3}{1-3}=\frac{4-2\sqrt{3}}{-2}=-2+\sqrt{3},$$ as you have already calculated, and so the *acute* signed angle from the positive real axis to the segment is $$\phi_1=\arctan\left(-2+\sqrt{3}\right).$$

Things are slightly more complicated for $z_2,$ since the segment to $z_2$ is in the second quadrant. You have correctly calculated the slope of the segment, though, since $$\frac{1+\sqrt{3}}{1-\sqrt{3}}=\frac{\left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)^2}{\left(1-\sqrt{3}\right)\cdot\left(1+\sqrt{3}\right)}=\frac{1+2\sqrt{3}+3}{1-3}=\frac{4+2\sqrt{3}}{-2}=-2-\sqrt{3}.$$ Unfortunately, the arctangent of this number would instead give the acute signed angle from the positive real axis to a ray from the origin to $-z_2,$ rather than to $z_2.$ Fortunately, we can simply add $\pi$ to that angle to get an angle from the positive real axis to $z_2,$ and so $$\phi_2=\pi+\arctan\left(-2-\sqrt{3}\right),$$ and indeed, $\tan(\phi_2)=-2-\sqrt{3},$ as you already found.

However, these are not the only angles that would work! Adding any integer multiple of $2\pi$ to either of them will work just as well.

Comment: Excellent answer!  I did fiddle around with this a bit and discovered the angles for each to be $-5 \pi/12$ and $-\pi/12$, which when subtracted come out to $-\pi/3$.  Then $e^{-i\pi/3} = -1/2 + i\sqrt {3}/2$ as before.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like you may have forgotten to add $\pi$ to the arctangent of $-2-\sqrt{3}.$ That gets an angle of $7\pi/12$ instead of $-5\pi/12,$ yielding a difference of $-2\pi/3,$ which instead gets the (correct) answer of $-1/2-i\sqrt{3}/2.$

Comment: Noted - I added a post above that was in the spirit of the question and I included that information with it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer that's in the spirit of the question. I've placed them under spoilers.

> Let $u = 1+\sqrt 3$ and $v = 1 - \sqrt 3$ so that $z_1 = u+iv$ and $z_2 = v+iu$.  Hence $$\dfrac {z_1}{z_2} = \dfrac {u+iv}{v+iu}$$ Clear the denominator of imaginary numbers by multiplying by the conjugate of $v+iu$, i.e. $v-iu = \overline {z_2}$ to get $$\dfrac {z_1}{z_2} = \dfrac {2uv+i(v^2-u^2)}{u^2 + v^2}$$  Separating real and imaginary parts we have $$\mathfrak{Re} \left(\dfrac {z_1}{z_2}\right) = \dfrac {2uv}{u^2+v^2} \\ \mathfrak{Im} \left(\dfrac {z_1}{z_2}\right) = \dfrac {v^2-u^2}{u^2+v^2}$$  Substituting the values of $u$ and $v$ we get $$\mathfrak{Re} \left(\dfrac {z_1}{z_2}\right) = \dfrac {2(1+\sqrt {3})(1-\sqrt{3})}{1+(\sqrt{3})^2+(1-(\sqrt{3})^2}=\dfrac {(2)(1-3)}{8} = -\dfrac {1}{2} \\ \mathfrak{Im} \left(\dfrac {z_1}{z_2}\right) = \dfrac {(1-\sqrt {3})^2-(1+\sqrt{3})^2}{1+(\sqrt{3})^2+(1-(\sqrt{3})^2}=\dfrac {-4 \sqrt{3}}{8} = -\dfrac {\sqrt{3}} {2}$$  Putting those items together we get $$\dfrac {z_1}{z_2} = -\dfrac {1}{2}-\dfrac {i \sqrt {3}}{2}$$

To find the answer in exponentials...

> $$|z_1| = |z_2| = \sqrt {8}$$ $$\arg {z_1} = \arctan \dfrac {1-\sqrt 3}{1+\sqrt 3} = \arctan (-2 + \sqrt {3}) = -\dfrac {\pi}{12} \\ \arg {z_2} = \pi + \arctan \dfrac {1+\sqrt 3}{1-\sqrt 3} = \pi + \arctan (- 2 -\sqrt{3}) = \dfrac {7\pi}{12}$$  Thus... $$\dfrac {z_1}{z_2} = \dfrac {\sqrt{8}e^{-i\pi/12}}{\sqrt{8}e^{7i\pi/12}} = e^{-i\pi/12-7i\pi/12} = e^{-8i\pi/12} = e^{-2i\pi/3} \\ e^{-2i\pi/3} \rightarrow \cos (-2\pi/3) + i \sin (2\pi/3) = -\dfrac {1}{2}-\dfrac {i \sqrt {3}}{2}$$

Comment: The arctangent function on the reals takes values in the interval $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right),$ so won't return a value of $\frac{7\pi}{12}.$ Instead, it returns $-\frac{5\pi}{12},$ as you noted before. This is $\arg(-z_2),$ and using it, instead, gets you the complex conjugate of the right answer, as you found before. Aside from that, this is really solid! +1